# How to upgrade php version on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, laravel

I'm trying to get my Laravel project to work. But when I use composer update it says the following:

This package requires php >=5.6.4 but your PHP version (5.5.12) does not satisfy that requirement.

I'm using WAMP which runs php version 7.0.4 this is also confirmed in the browser if I echo the php version. But when I use **php -v** in the console it shows that I'm using PHP version 5.5.12 (cli).

I've searched a bit around on google and I found out that it uses my windows PHP version instead of my webserver's version. But I couldn't find out how to update my  PHP version on Windows.

My PATH contents are as shown in the following image

[image]

Comment: This means you have yet another installation of `PHP` in your system. Check your `Programs` in `Control Panel` and remove such installation

Comment: PHP CLI and PHP (F)CGI (or even Apache Prefork-MPM) are independent from each other and do not need to use the same PHP version.

Comment: Add the contents of your `PATH` variable to the question

Comment: @HuzaibShafi Updated the post Still doesn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 41):

You can uninstall composer, and while re-installing it will ask you to point at your PHP directory which is going to be C:\wamp64\bin\php (usually) at that point you can choose which PHP version you would want to use. good luck.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer. Worked like a pro.

Comment: Work Like A Super Pro

Comment: You don't have to uninstall: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193976/3927450

Answer (score 5):

This means you have yet another installation of `PHP` in your system. Check your `Programs` in `Control Panel` and remove such installation.

However, you can modify your `PATH` environment variable as well. [Procedure](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Just remove the path that points to any `PHP` installation directory.

Else, otherwise, if you are unsure about changing the `PATH` variable (which can lead to serious problems if not set well), you can just delete the directory that the `PATH` variable points to.... (I mean the `PHP` directory)

The totally better solution is to add the path of your `PHP7` bin directory at the beginning of the `PATH` variable. You should also make available `composer` in this `PHP7` bin directory.

Such as, replace the `C:\php` in your path with `C:\wamp\bin\php7` or whatever the location of the `PHP7` path is..

Comment: I can't find something what has to do with a PHP version in my PATH there are only 3 things in there, one for composer (which might be it), npm and windowsApps

Comment: the directory which contains the `composer`, does that directory contain `php.exe` file as well?

Comment: it only contains the autoload files no php.exe, I've just downloaded php version 7 should I try and link that in the PATH file?

Answer (score 3):

To update PHP on Windows 10.

You must put the folder of the new PHP version in the same folder as the old.
You rename the old folder or you delete it, prefer rename the old folder,
now you write in a terminal console

```
php - v
```

PHP automatically check for a new version

Comment: Very Simple Approach

Answer (score 1):

if you had installed before xampp/wampp and composer globally you might had added php to you environment path to call it where ever you want, and now you want that composer use the new xampp with php the you recently installed, so go to system>advance tab> environment variable>  maybe in PATH then search if you have something like `C:\xampp\php` and edit to your new php location.

I had multiple versions off xampp for testing and composer globaly instaled for php 7.2

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the php version. Then you need to add the php version file you downloaded to system properties / advanced / environment variables / system variables / path for windows.