# Why can't I run composer install on ssh even though the php version is right?

Tags: php, ssh, centos

The server is using the default php version which is 5.6 and I need 7.1 so I installed the version 7.1 recently. When I run the command `php -v` it shows php 5.6 so I used `echo 'alias php="/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php"' >> ~/.bashrc` to change the alias and it was successful because it now shows php 7.1.32 (cli). But I still can't run `composer install` in my CentOS server using ssh and it shows the error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.1.3 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.1.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.1.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.0.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for beyondcode/laravel-dump-server ^1.0 -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-dump-server[1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0].
```

Comment: try to turn off the php 5.6 module and enable the php 7 that you recently installed, if i remember correctly you can switch version that you want your php to run

Comment: you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986206/2731607

Comment: @Kevin I just did using alias I am now using 7.1 but composer doesn't see it

Comment: composer will look at your `$PATH` and find the first executable PHP and use it to perform its task, so your alias won't work here

Comment: Can I redirect the `$PATH` so I can use the 7.1? @catcon

Comment: `PATH="/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php:${PATH}"` add this to your .bashrc, should work