# I can't install laravel 6 even my php is 7.2

Tags: laravel, installation

I working on my local computer(server). This is first time to install Laravel 6. By typing this command,

```
Laravel new project
```

The said

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.2 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for doctrine/lexer 1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/lexer[1.2.0].
    - doctrine/lexer 1.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v6.14.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.14.0].
    - laravel/framework v6.14.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker v2.2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v2.2.0].
    - laravel/tinker v2.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for monolog/monolog 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[2.0.2].
    - monolog/monolog 2.0.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for symfony/css-selector v5.0.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v5.0.4].
    - symfony/css-selector v5.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - Installation request for symfony/mime v5.0.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/mime[v5.0.4].
    - symfony/mime v5.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 8
    - Installation request for symfony/service-contracts v2.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/service-contracts[v2.0.1].
    - symfony/service-contracts v2.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 9
    - Installation request for symfony/translation-contracts v2.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation-contracts[v2.0.1].
    - symfony/translation-contracts v2.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 10
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[5.0.0].
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 11
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 7.0.10 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[7.0.10].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 7.0.10 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 12
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.5.2].
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 13
    - Installation request for sebastian/global-state 3.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/global-state[3.0.0].
    - sebastian/global-state 3.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 14
    - Installation request for sebastian/type 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by sebastian/type[1.1.3].
    - sebastian/type 1.1.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 15
    - doctrine/lexer 1.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - egulias/email-validator 2.1.15 requires doctrine/lexer ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/lexer[1.2.0].
    - Installation request for egulias/email-validator 2.1.15 -> satisfiable by egulias/email-validator[2.1.15].
```

I am using wamp server

[image]

My composer version is

[image]

CLI version

[image]

How can I fix this? thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share the error message in readable form. I would assume that you are not running PHP v 7.2 in your shell, but v 7.1.26 as given in that error message

Comment: php version on your cli might be different than 7.2, open the terminal from wamp control panel, I know you can do that from xampp control panel not sure if it is same with wamp

Comment: hi @NicoHaase I just update my question.

Comment: hi @KhanShahrukh please take a look at my updated question. The CLI version is already 7.2 but still having the error

Comment: If that error message still states that you are using PHP 7.1.26, you are still using that version for your CLI

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your command line is using a different version of PHP (it seems HHVM).
Try type

```
where php
```

in a command prompt and check if the given path is the same inside the WAMP installation folder

Comment: here's the result E:\wamp64\www\poms>where php 
E:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.26\php.exe

Comment: ohh it says my php is 7.1... but my wamp said 7.2?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986139/how-to-change-php-version-used-by-composer